# Мне нужно прибавить время с команды datetime.strftime(datetime.now() при помощи timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
f = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%d %m %Y")
b = timedelta(days = 5)
V = f + b
```

Мне нужно каким то образом сложить это, помогите пожалуйста!
Я понимаю в чём проблема, но не понимаю как её решить...

Answer (score 4):

Вы зачем-то преобразовываете текущую дату-время (`now()`) в строку с помощью `strftime`, потом к этой строке пытаетесь прибавить изменение времени (`timedelta`). Просто не преобразовывайте дату-время в строку, а сразу прибавляйте ваш `timedelta`, и только в конце (когда нужно вывести результат) преобразовывайте в строку:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 

v = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=5)
print(v.strftime("%d %m %Y"))  # 30 11 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
datetime.combine(date.today(), time()) + timedelta(hours=2)
```